# GCP Organisation Deleted

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, g-suite

I'm facing an interesting problem

I created a gsuite account with the xxx.domain then I created GCP with that gsuite mail account. After that we decided to use standard gmail account as the  administrator. We added a new email address to GCP as the owner.

After two months we decided to close the gsuite account to not pay for unused email address, we canceled it.

Then our compute engine, datastore, and snapshots, in other words, the whole project got shutdown. Now I can't restore the project because gcp says it's created by the organisation.

We subscribed with the domain to gsuite again to restore but old organisation ID is not applied so it was created with the new id.

Now, we can restore resources we used to be owners of the project but we're not given permission to restore.

what can we do? how we can restore resources before they were permanently deleted?

Comment: Since you closed/deleted your GSuite or Google account, that behavior appeared. Have you tried to [recover](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6236295) that account ?

Comment: account not recorveryable, gcp support fixed that account but now i face with bucket permission problems, and the solution just can handle by google engineers as i see.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the bucket permission problems and if it has any relation with the previous issue ?